# Pattern of multiple measurement device data

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to find pattern between data from two different source. I have aircraft altitude data from GPS and pressure sensor. Both data reference is mean sea level. I found discrepancies between these two data at same time. So, I would like to find pattern (if any), how they deviate from each other. Is there any kind of algorithm or approach I can apply?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to determine altitude from a pressure sensor, then you're simply performing an estimate based on how much air (and water in the air) weighs, given a reference pressure at sea level.

This changes based on the weather and where you are in the world, so you need to be looking up the current reference sea-level pressure for where you are in the world, and given your weather:

https://www.weather.gov/ppg/gfs_slp

Check the library you're using for your pressure sensor, there should be a place where you can change your reference air pressure at sea level.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the differences rather than the absolute value.

For example, if your airplane drops by 300 ft in a rather short period of time, how much does the air pressure change? This would remove *some* of the bias that comes from location and weather.

In other words, try to plot

$height[t+1 min] - height[t]$ vs. $pressure[t+1 min]-pressure[t]$

or

$(pressure[t+1 min]-pressure[t])/pressure[t]$

and look for patterns there.

Answer (score 0):

You have two-dimensional data. The easiest way to do this is *look at the data* in the form of a [scatter plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatter_plot):

[image: scatterplot, source: wikipedia]

If there is a straight line with few deviations, all is well. Otherwise, you might do [as proposed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/297108/173120) and add the pressure corrections for the GPS data (it should contain location and time, too).